# Detect chromecast on AVD Device

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, chromecast

I've tried everything but my virtual device doesn't detect chromecast.
I think this happens because the virtual device is connected via 3g and not via WIFI.
Does anyone know any solution for this? I'm an apple user and I'm not thinking about buying an android right now :/

Comment: I will be stunned if the Android emulator can interact with a Chromecast.

Answer (score 2):

An AVD device is emulated, its network state is emulated, it doesn't have access to your local network (for obvious security reasons), so I don't think you can make it detect your Chromecast.

I don't know what you need this connection for, but you can make it work using VirtulBox. In that, you can use Bridged mode, so your emulator works like a real network device.

My source: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Chromecast/comments/3zw3wg/trying_to_get_genymotion_or_other_android/)